# How to implement search for large data using Akavache?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, akavache

I have been working in an android application using **Xamarin Forms** and using **Akavache** for storing data locally in device. Until now it's all prefect, but now I need to save some more data(around 10 to 20 thousand records) and provide **search functionality with in that data**. What would be best solution to implement this type of functionality **using Akavache**?

Comment: `Akavache` is a Key|Value store and has no search feature on the `Value` as the Value is stored in a SQLite table (`CacheElement`) as a byte array... You would be much better off using a SQLite ORM/framework or Realm for Xamarin.

Answer (score 4):

I would not use Akavache to accomplish that, why? well, because you would either have to save all data in a single key then for the searching you will need to load all data (again) then do filtering with LINQ, or you will need to do a dirty magic to make each row having its own key in the Akavache dictionary.

Don't shoot yourself in the foot and use SQLite.Net-PCL instead. Setup is easy and querying later will less painful.

Comment: there can be more pain using SQlite.net PCL in fact. if you will have relational data with 3-4 layers and you want to cascade delete action. for example, you have exam-student-school. you want to delete school and want all related students and exams removed as well. this is a pain in SQLIte.Net, it runs slow. Same goes for updates and deletes.